# C# SQLite: how to select values from table where values are in c# list

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing a C# form application using SQLite as my Database provider. 
I have a Checkedlistbox listing all products and I read the checked Id's into a c# List. So far so good. Now I want to select from Table PRODUCTS all the products with the Ids from the list (so basically, I want to select the checked products). Previously I have done this using LINQ by using:
... `where lstids.Contains(p.id)`.

But in SQLite I am kinda lost. I have tried the following:

```
string query = "Select * from PRODUCTS where id in  "+ lstids;
```

but it returns a null value.

Any ideas?

Best regards,

Flavio Justino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do proper `IN` statement in `SQLLite` you need to give it as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID in (id1, id2, id3)
```

`lstids` is probably a `list`, `collection` and it's `ToString()` is not giving right data.

Try that:

```
var ids = string.Join(",", lstids.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID in ({0})", ids)
```